# drupal input filter example

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, input-filtering

I'm trying to write an input filter that turns everything that starts with http and ends in .mp3 into an audio element, so:

`http://google.com/file.mp3` -> `<audio src='http://google.com/file.mp3' />`

The regexp is no problem for me, just not sure how to construct the module.

A simple example that would allow me to add many additional rules would be very helpful, thanks.

I know about the custom filter module, but it has quite a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you simply need to implement [hook_filter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_filter/6) in your custom module.  That page lists a detailed sample module [filter_example.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_example_filter/6).

Comment: +1 - the linked example covers anything that's needed pretty well, but one could also look at the standard filter implementation in Drupal core: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_filter/6